# How to check whether a file exists in a particular directory in perl?

Tags: perl

How to check whether a particular file exists in a particular directory in perl?
Obvious method of checking that absolute directory name is prefix of absolute file name doesn't works as sometime absolute directory name is like /a/b/c/..

Answer (score 1):

[`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)'s `find` function could be used:

### Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                    

use strict;                                                                                            
use warnings;                                                                                          

use File::Find 'find';                                                                                 


# file 'foo' in path 'a/b/c'
my $file      = 'foo';                                                                                 
my $directory = 'a';                                                                                   

sub check_existance {                                                                              
    if ( -e $_ && $_ eq $file ) {                                                                      
        print "Found file '$_' in directory '$File::Find::dir'\n";                                     
    }                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                      

find( \&check_existance, $directory );
```

### Output

```
Found file 'foo' in directory 'a/b/c'
```

Comment: what if there are symbolic links in a directory, then would it search in them also?

Comment: abc15: The above program does not follow symbolic links. However, you could pass a `follow` option to the `find` function. Refer the documentation for `File::Find`: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the exact path you could use [`find2perl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html). It generates [`File::Find::find()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) code for you. To execute the command immediately:

```
$ find2perl /path/to/dir -name filename.txt -exec echo exists {} | perl
```

#### Code generated by `find2perl`

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell

use strict;
use File::Find ();

# Set the variable $File::Find::dont_use_nlink if you're using AFS,
# since AFS cheats.

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

sub wanted;
sub doexec ($@);

use Cwd ();
my $cwd = Cwd::cwd();

# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '/path/to/dir');
exit;

sub wanted {
    /^filename\.txt\z/s &&
    doexec(0, 'echo','exists','{}');
}

sub doexec ($@) {
    my $ok = shift;
    my @command = @_; # copy so we don't try to s/// aliases to constants
    for my $word (@command)
        { $word =~ s#{}#$name#g }
    if ($ok) {
        my $old = select(STDOUT);
        $| = 1;
        print "@command";
        select($old);
        return 0 unless <STDIN> =~ /^y/;
    }
    chdir $cwd; #sigh
    system @command;
    chdir $File::Find::dir;
    return !$?;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (-e "/path/to/file/filename.txt") {
   print("file exists");
}
```

?

Comment: It will not work as I don't know the path of file. There may be another directory in known directory.

Comment: Ah, you mean look for it in any subdirectories contained within the known directory? There's a File::Find module in CPAN which does this for you: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html